# Running node index.js does nothing

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

I am trying to follow a simple tutorial on setting up algolia which one can find here.

https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/indexing/3rd-party-service/firebase-algolia/

I literally copy the code word for word into an index.js file.

When I run node index.js in my terminal I get this

[image]

No success message. Nothing in algolia. Nothing. I have included my code is there anything that anyone noties that I may have done wrong. This has been frustrating me for hours.

```
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const firebase = require('firebase');

// load values from the .env file in this directory into process.env
dotenv.load();

// configure firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
});
const database = firebase.database();

// configure algolia
const algolia = algoliasearch(
  process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
  process.env.ALGOLIA_API_KEY
);
const index = algolia.initIndex(process.env.ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);

  // Get all contacts from Firebase
  database.ref('/events').once('value', event => {
    console.log('index is', index);

    // Build an array of all records to push to Algolia
    const records = [];
    event.forEach(event => {

      // get the key and data from the snapshot
      const childKey = event.key;
      const childData = event.val();
      // We set the Algolia objectID as the Firebase .key
      childData.objectID = childKey;
      // Add object for indexing
      console.log('child data is', childData);

      records.push(childData);
    });

    // Add or update new objects
    index
      .saveObjects(records)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('records are', records);

        console.log('Events imported into Algolia');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error when importing events into Algolia', error);
        process.exit(1);
      });
  });
```

I have followed all steps in the tutorial. I even ran it again everytime I run node index.js nothing happens no matter what I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with the database link. 
Check the value in the .env file of FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL , it should be something like: https://test123-dsacb.firebaseio.com

Comment: yeah so i logged the url and thats what it looks like

Comment: but when i go back to check algolia i see no records now

Comment: do you have any data in the events collection in firebase?

Comment: are you familar with algolia

Comment: TBH, first time heard about it. Also first time testing smth with firebase :D

Answer (score 12):

Happened to me, the issue was I haven't actually saved the index.js file. Once I saved it, it worked.

Comment: believe it or not, it happened to me too xD!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Look it again:

https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/indexing/3rd-party-service/firebase-algolia/

It says first you need to install these modules:

```
npm install dotenv --save
npm install algoliasearch --save
npm install firebase --save
```

and then set your environment variable:

```
    export ALGOLIA_APP_ID=<algolia-app-id>
    export ALGOLIA_API_KEY=<algolia-api-key>
    export ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME='contacts'
    export FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL=https://<my-firebase-database>.firebaseio.com
```

Try these things, if you still gets nothing then I think you have to emit or call '/events' event from somewhere to console the `console.log('index is', index);` part.

Comment: it told me to setup my environment in a file called '.env' i did that

Comment: still does nothing

Comment: trust me i atlast followed all these steps before posting

Comment: Then check console is inside the `/events ` event or api or connection, so as per my understanding we have to `hit` the event to check the logs = `onsole.log('index is', index);`.

Comment: the database call never executes

Comment: i have a statement   console.log('before database');
in addition to     console.log('entered database call');
the second one never occurs

Comment: Have you reached inside `/events` ?

Comment: no I have not  reached inside the database.ref('/events') callback

Comment: Ok just set env variable through export to make sure your code is correct.

Comment: example? please

Comment: like `export YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE=<env_variable_value>`