# How can I get $node index.js to run index.js in my command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

Im trying to get my index.js file to run in my command line using the following code.

`$node index.js`

In the command line I type in the following:

`$node index.js`

This is what is returned to me:

As you can see there are no error messages, nothing.

I tried searching on stack overflow for a solution, and I found two posts that are similar to my post.

Here are those two posts:

[Running node index.js does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216276/running-node-index-js-does-nothing)

[Not getting any (node index.js) response in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60748987/not-getting-any-node-index-js-response-in-terminal)

However, the solutions presented are not applicable to my situation, since my code does not deal with creating and setting up a server. My code is only a hello world program.

My code in the index.js file is the following:

`console.log("Hello, world");`

I know for a fact node.js is installed correctly, because on the command line, I enter the following code:

`node --version`

I am returned the following:

`v13.5.0`

I even tried updating to node v13.6.0, but I get the same outcome as stated above.

My OS is windows 7

Node v13.6.0 is the last update that supports Windows 7

Comment: it may sound silly, but did you save your `index.html` file? can you show the output when you do: `type index.js` ?

Comment: @pandamakes You were right. When I saved index.js using the Atom txt editor, for some reason it did not save the file for me. So, I went ahead and saved it using notepad++ and it works!

Answer (score 0):

that means your index.js file runs well, but print out nothing in console.

for example, if i paste `const a = 1;` in a javascript file index.js,

`node index.js` will return nothing in console, that's fine. if you'd like to see your result, put `console.log(result)` in your index.js file

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, In my post I specified that my code does indeed contain ```console.log(result);``` . In my post I said the following:                                       
                                                                                                                                            My code in the index.js file is the following:

```console.log("Hello, world");```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use this command? Without the **$** Sign?

```
node index.js
```

If you have used this and still no result, you can try to run this command and see if a new file is created within the same directory. If created, your command is running successfully.

```
const fs = require("fs");
fs.writeFile("TestDocument.txt", "Hello content!", function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Saved!");
});
```

N.B. Your TestDocument.txt file should contain "Hello content!" if created successfully.

Comment: I have tried using your solution, but unfortunately nothing was created. There was no error, but no file was created in the directory where index.js exists.

Answer (score 0):

> Im trying to get my index.js file to run in my command line using the
> following code.
>
> $node index.js

Don't run `$node index.js`, you are in Windows 7, so you will need to run `node index.js`(without the `$`)
Hope you find the solution soon, Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Since the node is getting a blank file, it shows a blank result. You need to save the file, it is not showing the exact result because the file is not saved after you typed the code, please save the file after the code gets typed and you will see the expected result.